# Access 2007 - Create Query That Returns One Record Per Customer

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create a query that examines an order table and creates a recordset containing only the most recent order for each customer.  Each record in the order table contains an order ID, in this format:

```
ABC002
```

which means this is the second order placed by customer ABC.
Now, if the table contained six records with the following order IDs:

```
ABC001, ABC002, DEF001, DEF002, DEF003, XYZ001
```

I would want the output recordset to contain these records:

```
ABC002, DEF003, XYZ001
```

Each record is the most recent order for each customer.  I could accomplish this using VBA, but it runs quite slowly when there are many records in the table.  Can anyone suggest how to create a query that would accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a separate table for customer data? Is the length of each customer fixed to 3?

Comment: Please provide sample table data and expected output based on it